# How to stream files from Hdfs directory and its sub directories to kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-nifi, flume

Avro files with Json data are written to hdfs directory every few minutes. For example, If today's date is 26/01/2020, a hdfs directory with name 20200126 will be created. Then there will be lot of subdirectories from 01 to many within that hdfs directory. Each subdirectories will have many Avro files.

How can I stream these files to Kafka topic as soon as it is created in the HDFS ? After reading I can delete the files.

How can i automate this streaming?

Comment: Track the directories for which you have already streamed out the data periodically.

Comment: Executing ls and tracking will be an overhead and affects the performance.Is there anyway to notify as soon as a file arrives via Nifi or any other tool?

Comment: Spark Streaming can watch files, so can Nifi, but IDK the processor

Comment: A better pattern usually is to take whatever is _writing_ the data to HDFS, get it to write the data to Kafka. Either Kafka can then write the data to HDFS instead, or just leave it as is but at least you have the events in Kafka itself then.

Comment: @cricket_007 Can spark streaming will check for recursive directories

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I don't have the control to write to Kafka dorectly.Files are pushed by the system

Comment: It takes a directory, I don't remember about recursive, but in most cases, a landing zone folder is just flat. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#file-streams  Also, can you clarify what you mean by you "dont have write access to Kafka"? Flume spooldir would also work, but I think NiFi is nicer to use, IMO